# Auto updating an html/angular app in client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an app using angular. The app will run on the clients computer. When an update is there it will download a zip file from the server and upgrade the required files.

I guess js and html is incapable of copying and modifying files. Our first idea was to run a background application on the os to check for updates and do the updates as necessary. But what other approaches are there to achieve this?

Comment: None. Not through in-browser JS alone anwyway. Can't you just host the app? Or get the client to download/update the zip?

Comment: this post may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056808/detect-application-version-change-on-a-single-page-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the application is offline, you can still host it, just use AppCache or something like it.

See this post for a tutorial:

```
http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-offline-html5-apps-with-appcache/
```

Comment: I think you have pointed me to the correct way. Why didn't i think of this --duh