# Axios get access to response header fields

Tags: http-headers, es6-promise, axios

I'm building a frontend app with React and Redux and I'm using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to perform my requests. I would like to get access to all the fields in the header of the response. In my browser I can inspect the header and I can see that all the fields that I need are present(such as token, uid, etc...), but when I call

```
const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/sign_in`, props);
request.then((response)=>{
  console.log(response.headers);
});
```

I get just

```
Object {content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", cache-control: "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}
```

Here my browser network tab,as you can see all the other fields are present.

[image]

Bests.

Comment: If you print out axios.defaults.headers does that give you any of the one's you're missing? Some headers are configured at that level, not at that of each request (see https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#global-axios-defaults)

Comment: Is not it `axios.defaults.headers` for configure the REQUEST header params? I need to access the RESPONSE one. @BenHare

Comment: BTW, what you called request, is not a request. It's a promise for your response. Your request was what you passed to the post() method as arguments.

Answer (score 556, accepted):

In case of CORS requests, browsers can only access the following response headers by default:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

If you would like your client app to be able to access other headers, you need to set the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header on the server:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Token, Uid
```

Comment: My bad I forgot to expose that fields.

Comment: If you are using Rails with Rack-Cors you need to set `expose: ['Access-Token', 'Uid']` on the origin like: `resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head], expose: ['Access-Token', 'Uid']`

Comment: I don't get it. If they are not exposed, why are the additional headers visible in the browser but not in the axios response?

Comment: @adanilev, browsers allow you to see them for debugging purposes, but prevent you from accessing them through APIs for security reasons. It prevents clients from getting secured credentials from servers, allowing the server to determine what access a client has.  TLDR: it's done on purpose for security

Comment: I have this in my NGINX confg file...

`'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization, X-Suggested-Filename, content-disposition' always;`

Still only see `content-type: "application/pdf"`

really need to pull `content-disposition`

Comment: In my grails server app i have set expose headers as cors.expose.headers = ['authorization'] and i am seeing the Access-Control-Expose-Headers : Authorization in my network tab as well. But i am not able to get it from axios response. 
Here also in @TWONEKSONE question, network tab already contains Access-Control-Expose-Headers : Authorization but why wasn't he able to access the headers? Please help.

Comment: I solved it by adding  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Custom-Header") in PHP back-end.

Comment: Thanks. Worked in Java Spring `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Token","yourToken");` where response is the `HttpServletResponse`

Answer (score 47):

This really helped me, thanks Nick Uraltsev for your answer.

For those of you using **nodejs** with [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#usage):

```js
...
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  exposedHeaders: 'Authorization',
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
...
```

In the case you are sending the response in the way of `` res.header('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`).send(); ``

Comment: For those wondering, you could pass an array here too: exposedHeaders: ['Authorization','X-Total-Count']

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the same problem. I did this in my `WebSecurity.java`, it's about the `setExposedHeaders` method in the CORS configuration.

```java
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(FRONT_END_SERVER));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With","Origin","Content-Type","Accept","Authorization"));
    
    // This allow us to expose the headers
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, x-xsrf-token, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, " +
            "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 19):

Faced same problem in asp.net core
Hope this helps

```cs
public static class CorsConfig
{
    public static void AddCorsConfig(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                .WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination")
                );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer may be correct but at StackOverflow, it is discouraged to post code only answer. Please try to provide an explanation of how your answer solves the original question. please read this on how to [Write Better Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 9):

In axios CORS requests, browsers can access only few headers by default.

But if you need to access a custom header from response, you have to **send response** with  `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` form your backend server.

Hare is a example for Nodejs backend and Reactjs front end:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-xsrf-token');

return res.header("x-xsrf-token", token).status(200)
           .send({
                id: user.id,
                email: user.email,
            });
```

**res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-xsrf-token');**

for this line I can log my custom header like

```
axios.post("/login", {
            email: emailInput.current.value,
            password: passwordInput.current.value,
        })
        .then(function (response) {

            console.log(response.headers["x-xsrf-token"]);

        });
```

Without `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in your response you will get undefine in console log. Check your response header in network tab that it contains the header with your custom name with it.

Answer (score 7):

According to [official docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema):

This may help if you want the ***HTTP headers that the server responded with***. All header names are lower cased and can be accessed using the bracket notation. Example: `response.headers['content-type']` will give something like: headers: {},

Answer (score 7):

Custom HTTP headers can not be accessed on client-side due to CORS restrictions. You need to add Access-Control-Expose-Headers setting on the server-side.

What are Access-Control-Expose-Headers?
Please go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

By default only these HTTP headers are exposed:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Length
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

For custom HTTP headers, you need to customize Access-Control-Expose-Headers in response headers.

If you are using Django on the server side you can use `django-cors-headers` (https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) for CORS settings management.

For example, with `django-cors-headers` you can add a list of HTTP headers that are to be exposed to the browser by `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS` setting

```py
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
    'my-custom-header',
]
```

Answer (score 7):

There is one more hint that not in this conversation.
for asp.net core 3.1
first add the key that you need to put it in the header, something like this:

```
Response.Headers.Add("your-key-to-use-it-axios", "your-value");
```

where you define the cors policy (normaly is in `Startup.cs`) you should add this key to WithExposedHeaders like this.

```
          services.AddCors(options =>
        {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithExposedHeaders("your-key-to-use-it-axios"));
        });
    }
```

you can add all the keys here.
now in your client side you can easily access to the your-key-to-use-it-axios by using the response result.

```
          localStorage.setItem("your-key", response.headers["your-key-to-use-it-axios"]);
```

you can after use it in all the client side by accessing to it like this:

```
const jwt = localStorage.getItem("your-key")
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using Laravel 8 for the back-end side with CORS properly configured, add this line to `config/cors.php`:

`'exposed_headers' => ['Authorization'],`

Comment: Thank you for that. 
I tried the wildcard '*' , which did'nt work, but using your answer as help it really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

for django help

```
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
        'your header'
    ]
```

Comment: At least for Flask CORS, you can also pass a dict where each key is named `CORS_<property>` (in this case `expose_headers`) and pass it with the desired values in the `CORS(app, **cors_config)` statement. See docs [here](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration-options)

Answer (score 2):

For the SpringBoot2 just add

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "custom-header1, custom-header2");
```

to your CORS filter implementation code to have whitelisted `custom-header1` and  `custom-header2` etc

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
            .then(res =>{
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.headers['x-total-count']);
                setTotalRecords(res.headers['x-total-count']);
                setTableData(res.data);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Below the list of clear steps to make sure you don't need to spend the whole evening googling as I did. I address the matter of how to read the Authorization header in the axios **response** (!).

For the back-end I am using standard ExpressJS. I am using: `cors()` and `helmet()` middleware in Express with the empty configuration but the below works nonetheless.

1. Make sure your backend sends `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`. At the begining set it to `*` to eliminate other possibilities. In Express, this going to be:

```js
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*')
```

2. Make sure your backend sends `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. Don't confuse with the 1st. step as both sound similar. Set this to cover all the headers you want to read from. In my case:

```js
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,x-client-session')
```

3. In your front-end app, Axios will return "AxiosHeaders" type for the headers. You should have your headers exposed now. Specifically for Authorization use:

```js
const res = await axios(init)
const authHeader = res.headers.getAuthorization()
```

Even in the most up to date package version you may get TypeScript error that: *This expression is not callable* but it is.

This is it.

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Boot 2 if you don't want to use global CORS configuration, you can do it by method or class/controller level using `@CrossOrigin` adnotation with `exposedHeaders` atribute.

For example, to add header `authorization` for `YourController` methods:

```
@CrossOrigin(exposedHeaders = "authorization")
@RestController
public class YourController {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[expanding on what @vladimir said]

if you're using **Django**

and [`django-cors-headers`](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) to allow/control CORS,
you should set the following, in your `settings.py`

```
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['yourCustomHeader']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django without [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/), you can write custom middleware.

```py
class CustomCorsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'MY-HEADER, ANOTHER-HEADER'

        return response
```

You can also set other CORS heades here.

Then you should register your middleware by inserting it at the beggining of the `MIDDLEWARE` list in your project's `settings.py` file.

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'myapp.middleware.CustomCorsMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6 or up, this could work:

In your @Configuration class includes this:

```
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    
        //Allow several headers
        config.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        config.addAllowedHeader("X-Custom-Header");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Another-Header");
    
        // Expose custom headers
        config.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
        config.addExposedHeader("X-Custom-Header");
        config.addExposedHeader("Another-Header");
    
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

Be careful cause the previous configuration is so general.