# Can't get headers from Http POST request with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-headers, axios

I have this POST request with axios in React :

```
postRunSimulation(simulationId) {
  var requestAnalysis = `${configFile.web.backend}analysis/${simulationId}/run`;
  return axios.post(requestAnalysis)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.headers;
  }, function(error) {
    throw new Error('An error occurred : ' + error.status + ' - ' + error.statusText);
  });
},
```

The object I get in return has a `headers` property but it's empty. If I make the same call with Postman, I get the headers. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your back-end is running on a different host or port than the web app, the browser can only access the following 6 response headers by default: `Cache-Control`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, and `Pragma` (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931084/6218152) answer). If the server does not return any of them, the `headers` will be empty.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought it was sufficient to enable cross-origin requests !