# accessing response header via Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, response-headers

I'm using Axios to make a secure POST call to an API.
This returns an URL within the response headers under 'Location'.

I can see the URL being populated within Chrome's dev tools:

[image]

but the response inside JS from Axios (below) doesn't contain this information:

[image]

Any advice greatly received!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios get access to response header fields.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

Comment: Please find another detailed discussion regarding the same [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/746)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it occurs because you are doing a cors request that doesn't expose location header by default.

You need to add this Cors Configuration to your server side app.

Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location

as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers