# axios in response.headers doesn't show the x-operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, axios

I have a problem with the API response. We're using as backend service to register async user.

I want to check if the user are registered or not, but I don't have simply message as a response, but I need to check the headers:

**x-operation:operations/e18f9239-b66b-4a81-a7cb-622a40326057**
This header will tell me if I send api request to another endpoint if the user are registered with this email, or not.

In the Network section I have following Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8080
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 22 Nov 2017 17:33:20 GMT
Server:Kestrel
Vary:Origin
x-operation:operations/e18f9239-b66b-4a81-a7cb-622a40326057
x-resource:account
```

To my request I am using axios library (react-app)

```
export function signupUser({ email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/sign-up`, { email, password })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('response', response)
      // browserHistory.push('/signin');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // dispatch(authError(error.data.error))
      console.log('error', error)
    })
  }
}
```

The problem is to handling the response. I need to check the x-operation, but the x-operation in my response doesn't appear.

When I do my console.log(response) in .then I have headers: {} empty. 
Here is the console.log(response)

```
response 
{data: "", status: 202, statusText: "Accepted", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config:
{transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", adapter: ƒ, …}
data:""
headers:{}
request:XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status:202
statusText:"Accepted"
```

How can I check the response x-operation in headers, if I don't have it in axios response, only appear in Network section?

Answer (score 12):

Try taking a look at this SO post: [Axios get access to response header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

You need to make sure your server is configured to allow the client to access those headers, something like: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-operation` I believe.

Comment: Yes, I found this topic after create a new one here. I asked the back-end service about that issue. Will present the solution when they response me. Thanks