# Get Cookie from axios response using cors on the server side

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, cors

I run Vue.js 2.5.2 and axios 0.17.1 against a Node.js server using express 4.16.2 and cors 2.8.4.

When I do a login

```
axios.post('/login', {"username": "a", "password": "b").then((response) => {
    console.log(response.headers['set-cookie']);
}
```

I get `undefined` as output. On other [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields/37931084) they told to set the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Token, Uid`. I did this in my server-config like this:

```
const express = require('express'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
cors = require('cors'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
const server = express();

server.use(cookieParser());
server.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

server.use(cors({
  "origin": "*", 
  "credentials": true,
  "exposedHeaders": ["Uid", "Access-Token"]
  // same for "Uid, Access-Token"
  // Adding "set-cookie" to this list did not work.
}));
```

I can see in the Chrome Developer Toolbar, that `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`-Option is set in the OPTION-Request and the POST-Request. Also in the POST-Request I can see the set-cookie-header. But the log of `response.headers['set-cookie']` is still undefined.

---

Edit:

This behavior is in the development-mode:
Server is running on localhost:3000, client is running on localhost:8080.

When I build the vue.js-client for production mode so that both runs on localhost:3000, it works.

---

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to add the `set-cookie` to the `exposedHeaders` list, as that says what headers the client is allowed to access

Comment: Hi Ferrybig, no sadly this did not work. In the meantime I noticed something else... I edited my post

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, I removed everything about authentication out of my project and switched to keycloak. So I authenticate in my client against keycloak and get a token. Then I send the token along with my request to the server and the server checks this token against keycloak too.

Answer (score 4):

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` (which is what 'controls' whether cookies and other 'credentials' can be used in a CORS request) is **not compatible** with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` - you need to specify the exact origin from which the request is coming in the ACAO response header if you want to use cookies.

Basically, extract the `Origin` request header and ensure that it is 'mirrored back' in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. In your case, it will probably be `https://localhost:8080`, but you shouldn't hardcode it - always extract it from the `Origin` request header.

So the answer should be as simple as specifying the value of the `Origin` request header in the `server.use.cors.origin` value.