# Correctly returning x-auth token from API

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making an API using Express.

I'm using JWTs for authentication. My code:

```
 user
    .generateAuthToken(body.loginPhrase)
    .then((token) => {
      res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send({ message: err.message }));
```

This all works fine.

However, I can't see the `x-auth` header on the client (React). I can see the `Content-Type` header.

How can I make the `x-auth` header visible to the client, which is using Axios?

Using the `cors` package, on the server I have:

```
const corsOptions = {
  allowedHeaders: ['x-auth'],
};
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So what you have, at least from an Express point of view, looks fine - axios doesn't hide custom headers by default perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios get access to response header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong config. The correct config is:

```
const corsOptions = {
  exposedHeaders: ['x-auth'],
};
```