# Django doesn't return request headers to axios

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to receive a session cookie with axios from a django rest framework backend. I'm using django sessions described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/).

When I make a post from the command line with httpie, I see several headers, including `Set-Cookie` with the session token:

```
http post http://example.com:8000/api/ key1=val1 key2=val2
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 83
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2019 08:47:16 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.7
Set-Cookie: session=e30:1gk3KW:PVn6Pgj-gZQhQue6plWCAONePR4; 
Domain=*; expires=Thu, 31 Jan 2019 08:47:16 GMT; HttpOnly; Max- 
Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    <response params>
}
```

But when I do it from axios, the only response header is `Content-Type: application/json`.

I went for the kitchen sink approach with the CORS settings:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '*'
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '*'
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
    'Set-Cookie',
)       
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = (          
    'Set-Cookie',                  
)
```

but to no avail.

The view doesn't do much:

```
def post(self, request):
    request.session.create()
    request.session.save()
    return super().create(request)
```

nor does the axios code:

```
axios.post(
    URL,
    {
        key1: val1,
        key2: val2,
    }
)
.then(response => {whatever(response)})
```

I'm trying to figure out how to receive the other headers in axios, or at least the reason they're not being received in the first place. I get the feeling it has something to do with CORS, but I don't have a good way to debug it.

Comment: Just look at this link, it might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931084/5022847

Comment: That header is set by the CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS variable, which already contains Set-Cookie.