# Axios request doesn't return full response headers

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I need to get all response headers via following codes but it only returns 4 of them in response.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xy9dch7g/

```
axios
  .head('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
```

Axios returned headers: http://take.ms/5KqEBn

Expected headers: http://take.ms/SFVyl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like your client app to be able to access other headers, you need to set the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header on the server:

[Try this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

Comment: yes, that's right, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields