# axios response headers missing data when running in vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, http-headers, axios, authorization

I have simple vuejs application. In the main.js I have something like:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router/routes";
import store from "./store/root";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import { RootActions } from "./constants";
import axios from "axios";

axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/mzabriskie").then(function(response) {
  console.log({ headers: response.headers });
});
```

In the chrome console log I got these:

[image]

However in https://runkit.com/greenlaw110/5e92363de9be35001ab0481e with exactly the same code, I have much more headers printed out:

[image]

Question:

1. Why there is such a big difference between axios running in vuejs and a pure nodejs environment?
2. What I really want is to get the `Authorization` header of the response in my VueJs application, is this really doable in any way? (Note I have already put `Authorization` in the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` of the response to preflight request

Refer:

- https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/606
- https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/771
- [Axios get access to response header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All right, so here is the problem, the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` must also be presented in the headers of response to non prefight reqeust. After I exposed this headers to all response, I can get access to the `Authorization` header in my vuejs app.

Answer (score 9):

In the case of CORS requests, browsers can only access a few response headers by default, which are: **Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Type, Expires, Last-Modified, Pragma**

All the headers will be shown in the browser, but the client code won't be able to access these headers.

If you would like your client code to be able to access other headers *(example: Token)*, then we need to set the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header on the server, like shown below

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Token`

In the browser API response will show all headers we need
[image]

But the code won't be able to access the headers.

**Before setting the exposed headers**
[image]

**After setting the exposed headers on the server.**
The headers will show same in browser, but in addition browser/client code will be able to access the headers(Token)
[image]

This answer is based on the answer provided by [Nick Uraltsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6218152/nick-uraltsev) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931084/4337125

Answer (score 1):

At your app under cors ou need to enable `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

example

nestjs backend app

```
app.enableCors({
    exposedHeaders: 'session-id'
  });
```

Now your client app will be able to access that response header