# Wrong response from the server - It seems my FrontEnd is getting Options response instead of Post

Tags: spring-boot, rest, vue.js, spring-security, cors

I have read a lot about CORS, preflight etc, I know the problem is related to it, but couldn't figure out, what's going on here.

I'm using VueJs and SpringBoot with Spring Security and jsonwebtoken.

When I make a POST request /login on Postman:

```
{
    "username":"admin",
    "password":"password"
}
```

I got the right response with the expected token:

***http 200 with headers:***

```
{
    Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTYwODI5OTIxMn0.9oXFpm9DivR3DNPcBaoc_KgsqNdBJbkFq_oA4pBJbXF2iUwx7_XfBwv-Xcn-da9LS9M5zxd8oRslr_wdVyoQkA,
    X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
    Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
    Pragma:no-cache
    Expires:0
    X-Frame-Options:DENY
    Content-Length:0
}
```

However, when the front-End calls the service I got the following answer with the wrong header, there is no token:

***http 200 with headers***

```
{
    cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", 
    content-length: "0", expires: "0", pragma: "no-cache"
}
```

When I open the browser with security disabled it works fine as well, I got the expected token on the header...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

So it seems to be related to Cors indeed, but I don't get any Cors error message!

I used fiddler to track the requests and responses and I notice that the option method is happening, So my first question is, should the options response go up to the front-end? as far as I know the options stay within the browser boundary and then the browser makes the post request (if the server allowed).

**Options Request:**

```
OPTIONS http://ec2-52-4-252-232.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9090/login HTTP/1.1
Host: ec2-52-4-252-232.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9090
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6
```

**Options Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2020 14:58:56 GMT
```

**Post Request:**

```
POST http://ec2-52-4-252-232.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9090/login HTTP/1.1
Host: ec2-52-4-252-232.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9090
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 42
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: undefined
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
Referer: http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6

{
    "username":"admin",
    "password":"password"
}
```

**Post Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTYwODI5OTUzNn0.0UgsNHd9Aw9Ei5aq-k0y74BlxJ92-j7w-FrryZaDAwzLC1a2OpSH3rXhRWGIul3wqpWLbqJ7icNlM3d590UFWw
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2020 14:58:56 GMT
```

**Part of My front-end Code:**

```
        login({ commit }, user) {

            const cors = require('cors')({
                origin: true
            });
            const qs = require('querystring')
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                commit('auth_request')
                axios({
                    url: process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_ENDPOINT + '/login', data: user, method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

                })
                    .then(resp => {
                        console.log(resp.headers)
                        const token = resp.headers["authorization"]
                        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
                        commit('auth_success', token, user.username)
                        resolve(resp)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        commit('auth_error')
                        localStorage.removeItem('token')
                        reject(err)
                    })
            })
```

**Part of my Back-End Code:**

````
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()

                // filtra requisições de login
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                // filtra outras requisições para verificar a presença do JWT no header
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        List<String> allowOrigins = Arrays.asList("*");
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(allowOrigins);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(singletonList("*"));
        //in case authentication is enabled this flag MUST be set, otherwise CORS requests will fail
        //configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // cria uma conta default
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }
}```

Anyone knows what's going on here ? Why the Post response isn't coming to the front-end ?

I spend many hours but couldn't solve it, so I appreciate any help.
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually my problem wasn't related to options method as I thought, the problem was that I was missing the Access-Control-Expose-Headers which should also be presented in the headers of server response.

I just set it on my springboot app and it worked fine !

```
List<String> exposedHeaders = Arrays.asList("Authorization");
configuration.setExposedHeaders(exposedHeaders);
```

I got the answer from this one: [axios response headers missing data when running in vuejs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164197/axios-response-headers-missing-data-when-running-in-vuejs-app)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your Postman request with curl:

```
curl -vv -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://ec2-52-4-252-232.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9090/login -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"password"}'
```

Returns a 200 with the `Authorization` header filled in.

Can you run the frontend code with the Network tab in Developer Tools open and see how the POST request looks?
And possibly right-click and "copy as cURL" and then compare it to the curl request above.

Comment: the frontend's network tab got the same result as the fiddler i've described above, there is a options and then a post with a  right response, why my front-end is not getting the right response, it seems it is getting the options response. any idea ?