# Axios not showing Authorization Header In Response

Tags: reactjs, axios

Authorization header comes in network as can seen in picture. But it doesn't show in the axios response after I make a login request.

```
 response = await axios
    .post(apiUrl + "/login", 
    {
        "user": {
            email,
            password
        },
    }
    );
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g40o.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqMFh.png

Comment: did you try with `axios interceptor` , response interceptor?

Comment: Did you try to print `response.headers`

Comment: yes it doesnt show authorization header @AyyubKolsawala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could find an article over [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/771) which says that you need to enable `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in your backend app. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164197/axios-response-headers-missing-data-when-running-in-vuejs-app)