# How to get headers from http response in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, axios, http-headers, response, response-headers

I use axios to retrieve some data from backend. I send a request and i have a response. I want to read some of my headers. I've tried many things but no one is working.
My headers contains the following headers `'content-type', content-length', 'x-wp-total', 'x-wp-totalpages'`.

I've tried to get headers using `response.headers('content-type')` but i am getting error *response.headers is not function*. I am in trouble.

My question seem to be simple. Which is the syntax to get headers from response ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema?

```
  // `headers` the HTTP headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased and can be accessed using the bracket notation.
  // Example: `response.headers['content-type']`
  headers: {},
```

Related: [Response header fields and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

Answer (score 0):

based on your logs, it should be `response.headers["content-type"]`. Or you can also call `response.headers.contentType` usually also works.

Answer (score 0):

headers is the attribute of response. It is an object not function, so you cannot use it as a function like "headers()". If you want to visit the attribute of headers, you should use '.' or []