# Why does the Authorization header token does not get displayed in my browser

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I want to create a login system. I have a Spring Boot Api with a JWT-Token for security written with [this](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) tutorial. On my Front-End I use React JS and Axios for requests.

This is my axios configuration:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:8080',
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
});

export default api;
```

And this is the login function:

```
loginClickHandler = () => {
        const data = {
            "username":this.state.username,
            "password":this.state.password
        };
        api.post("/login",data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                if(response.data !== null) {
                    this.setState({
                        loggedIn:true,
                        userData:response.data
                    });
                }else{
                    this.showMessage(2,response.data.error)
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.showMessage(2,error);
            });
    };
```

The login function itself and everything else works fine, but I do not get the Authorization Token displayed in the browser as a header. This is the `console.log(response)` (only headers):

```
headers:
cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
content-length: "0"
expires: "0"
pragma: "no-cache"
```

However when I use Postman for the request, I get 14 headers and one of them is the **Authorization** header with the token in it as expected.

Now my question is, how I can get the header displayed in my browser so I can store it for later requests.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I just found that the Authorization Header gets displayed in the Network tab of the browser but not in the response.

**SOLUTION:**

I had to add this line in my `JWTAuthenticationFilter successfulAuthentication` method:

```
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",HEADER_STRING);
```

as @Jack Chen and @Sarthak Aggarwal suggested

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must be set on the server, not on the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the input,  but I don't think that this is related to the problem, since the request itself is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to set `The Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header set on server as it lets a server whitelist headers that browsers are allowed to access.`

Syntax:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: <header-name>[, <header-name>]*
```

Comment: For more information, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931084)

Answer (score 1):

You could not set header info in client request here:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:8080',
    // pass 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is not working!
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
});

export default api;
```

Because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), you could not get the correct response before set this header in your server side. You can according to [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) to set header in your Spring Boot service.

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but using NodeJs & Express,
to solve the problem I had to add this expose header:

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "<YourHeaderName>");
```

(very similar to your solution)

More info about setHeader method:
*response.setHeader(name, value) (Added in v0.4.0)*
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-response-setheader-method/