# Why isn't react component showing in my browser?

Tags: java, html, reactjs, spring-boot, web

I am experimenting with React but I have a small Problem, which wouldn't let me see the page in my Browser. For Info: I am working with SpringMvc and including React. these are my files:

#### `WebController.java`

```java
package mouad.meziani.combispringandreactcombo.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class WebController {

    @GetMapping()
    public String init(){
        return "main";
    }
}
```

#### `main.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="../static/JS/App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### `App.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CounterComponent from "../components/CounterComponent";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>My Page of Counter</h1>
            <CounterComponent />
        </>
    )
}

root.render(<App/>);
```

#### `CounterComponent.js`

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function CounterComponent(){
    const [count, setCount] = useState(() => { return 0; });

    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
            <span>{count}</span>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CounterComponent;
```

update: I have found the error but I don't know exactly why it is showing.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/static/JS/index.js 404 (Not Found)
Room:1  

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.ciuvo.com/api/analyze?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&version=2.1.4&tag=threesixty&uuid=74DB5A90-0740-4C73-8356-A9F8A76D2EB6' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
ciuvo-contentscript.js:5684 
      
GET https://api.ciuvo.com/api/analyze?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&version=2.1.4&tag=threesixty&uuid=74DB5A90-0740-4C73-8356-A9F8A76D2EB6 net::ERR_FAILED 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: because you havnt configured CORS, read what it is https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title

Comment: You have to add a Header in your Backend before sending it to the Frontend. Something like `addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",HEADER_STRING);`

This Question (from myself 3 years ago) might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009318/why-does-the-authorization-header-token-does-not-get-displayed-in-my-browser