# Cordova app doesn't have access to HTTP response headers

Tags: reactjs, cordova, axios, phonegap

I'm migrating a React 16 app to Apache Cordova (v10.0). I'm using the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) HTTP library.

When I run the original version, I my app has access to authentication response headers with a bearer token (etc) in the response object. But when I run the same app and make the same request from Cordova, I can't get the authentication tokens. The when I `console.log` the response object, the Cordova version only receives two headers: `cache-control` and `content-type`.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const myApi = axios.create({
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
});

    myApi.post(authenticationPath, {
      email: 'foo@example.com',
      password: 'bar'
    })
    .then( response => {
      console.log(response);
      // In the original version, response.headers has auth token, etc
      // In the Cordova version, response.headers only has cache-control + content-type
    })
```

Update: I checked the raw HTTP response in the dev tools and the missing headers *are* there. So it appears that my backend API is responding correctly, but for some reason javascript can't see them in the response object (in the Cordova version of my app)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my issue here: [Axios get access to response header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

TLDR = For CORS responses, the browser can only see a couple "safe" headers. To see the rest, the server needs to explicitly whitelist them with additional headers.