# having problem in accessing response headers Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to access response headers using axios. but some reason I cant get the entire response details.is there a way I can access **X-Pagination-Total-Items in response headers**

here a console log of what I'm getting
[image]
and here is what is present in my response headers
[image]

I want to access X-Pagination-Total-Items. how can I do it ?

Comment: this thread might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126869/11355290

Comment: I'm not using NodeJS to setup server. I'm getting this response from third party API. Is there any other way?