# Can't access x-request-id header with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a simple post request with axios:

```
axios.post('my endpoint', values).then(res => console.log(res.headers));
```

axios is listing those values as headers:

```
cache-control: "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
content-length: "13757"
content-type: "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
```

but when I check the network tab in chrome, I can see those values under `response headers`:

```
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8080
access-control-expose-headers: Total,Total-Pages
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
content-length: 13757
content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 02 Sep 2021 19:37:42 GMT
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 385
x-request-id: FqEYfGCtbcHGzzwASr4C
```

I need to access the `x-request-id` header, but there is no way to get this with axios or fetch.

I saw some messages about the header being blocked by cors, but I have `X-Request-Id` in my `access-control-allow-headers`

Someone has any idea how to get this header with axios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to specify this on the server so that axios has access to the specific headers you require.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931084/8818020

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I need, thank you :)