# Can't access Content-Disposition in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, response-headers

I have a React JS application where I send a GET request with axios. In the browser, in the `Response Headers` section, when I send the request I get `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="image123.pdf"`, but when I try to get this in React, I don't get any field with this name. So when I try to access the `response.headers['content-disposition']`, I don't get anything.

Is it possible to read this header key using React JS using axios?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios get access to response header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, did you find any solution?
I can see the content-disposition in the API response from network tab but when I make Axios request i'm not getting it in my response header,

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure that appropriate access has been granted from the server side for this matter through CORS. You can perform a quick comparison with the following piece of code to make sure that there is no issue for server-side access to this specific matter.
check it in server:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Disposition');
```

The next step for you is to make sure that you are sending these two items from the client side to the server.

set in header (client-side):

```
responseType: 'blob',
withCredentials: true,
```