# Axios doesn't not receiving the header I set

Tags: javascript, axios, cors

I deploy the `Server.cjs` file on the server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
const port = 3001;
app.use(cors())

app.get("/download", (req, res) =>{
    const file_uniquename = req.query.file_uniquename
    const { file_originalname, mimetype, filepath } = ...

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' +  file_originalname)
    res.setHeader('Contect-type', mimetype)
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath)
    stream.pipe(res)
  }
})


app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`App listening at :${port}`);});
```

I am trying to use axios to receive file streams and filenames on the front end, I see the headers I set in the `network` tab in developer tools, but the res received by axios has empty headers. Why?

```
//import fileDownload from 'js-file-download'

axios.get(serverurl + 'download', { params: { file_uniquename: file_uniquename }}）
    .then(res => {
        //fileDownload(res.data)
        //console.log(res.headers['Content-disposition'])
        console.log(res.headers)
    });
```

Comment: so `res.headers` is empty? or just `res.headers['Content-disposition']` ... I think axios may  have that as `res.headers['content-disposition']` - i.e. all lower case

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey,bro. I found the solution and I will write the solution below, thank you for your attention to this problem.

Comment: I await with anticip......

Comment: Finished @JaromandaX

Comment: ...pation ... :p of course, if you had mentioned that the error was due to CORS, I would've been able to direct you to the issue immediately :p

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks for the Nick Uraltsev's answer at "[Axios get access to response header fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897523/axios-get-access-to-response-header-fields)", and the comment of Old Man Walter.

- Because of `cors`, only some of the headers will be accessed by the browser. So we should use `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to make the browser access the other headers.

```
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Suggested-Filename");
    res.setHeader("X-Suggested-Filename", originalname);

    fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(res)
```

- In addition, the spelling of `Contect-type` is wrong, which should be `Content-Type`, which should not be seen as a big problem.