# Axios API Response Headers are being shown in network call but can't access in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net

I need resposne headers of Axios API get call in my aaplication, the app is in React js and I'm trying to access **Us....Etag** key and here is my code:

```
      const response = await dotnetApiClient().get(`/my-api`);
      const headers = response.headers;
      const etag = headers["Us....Etag"];
      console.log("Keys: ", etag);
```

but I'm getting undefined in console.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77919006/23309989) answer your question?

Comment: @Chukwujiobi I think by mistake you've pasted my  question's link in your comment. Can you please check link ?

Comment: Ahh yes [this is the one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37897523/16770846).

Comment: Hey @ChukwujiobiCanon thank you this link helps me.