# deployed react web app requires hard refresh

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Bootstrapped with create-react-app (v1.0.13). Whenever I update the source & redeploy users need to hard refresh to get the new content. I've included non-cache header in index.html:

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />`

& turned off provided service workers. Also change the .js filename (and reference in index.html) in build folder before deploying.

Comment: Disable caching or use a chunkhash so a changed file will have a new name

Comment: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2328

Comment: that's not a solution, just a link that goes to another link that goes deep into webpack which is something create-react-app helps to avoid.

Comment: It is not an answer, only a comment that it is currently not implemented. And a link to an issue with an article how to use chunkhashs with webpack.

Comment: create-react-app does change the .js file name every time you make a build. The link you provided is just talking about making the filenames follow correct versioning. Not relevant to the problem.

Comment: ok, but if every file (except .html) has a different name after it is changed there should be no problem with caching these files

Comment: I agree, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, and this answer was the most helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48738828/2136562

Answer (score 3):

I was able to remove caching by doing the following:

- adding the following to  in index.html

  `<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />`
- inserting the following to the js

  `import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
  unregister()`
- changing cloudflare caching expiration to 'respect existing headers' at https://www.cloudflare.com/a/caching/

It is unclear which of these (or all of these) are actually required but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming in the future -- all you need is the

```
{unregister} from ./registerServiceWorker

unregister();
```

This helped my create-react-app work with hosts like gh-pages and netlify.

Comment: Hi Mathew, where did you place these line of code in order to make this work?

Comment: What syntax is ths?

Comment: Javascript, and index.js

Comment: where to put this script?