# Firebase hosting no-cache for Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to get my Angular app's index page not to cache.  I've formatted my firebase.json rules according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589821/firebase-hosting-how-to-prevent-caching-for-the-index-html-of-an-spa):

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix functions run build"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers" : [{
      "source": "/**",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        }
      ]
    },
      {
        "source":
        "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=604800"
          }
        ]
      }]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

It appears that the rules are working fine if I check the the browser console:

[image: firebase no cache result]

However, it is still loading stale files and I need to hard reload in order to see the changes.  Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out.  I was not using the `-prod` flag when running `ng build`, so the the js and css bundles were not getting hashes added to their name (i.e. `main.bf49565a4e90c0772548.bundle.js`), so those files were still getting cached.