# Ionic app hosted on firebase requires cache clear

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, caching, firebase-hosting

I have an ionic 4 app hosted on firebase and when I push an update, my users have to clear their cache to load the newest version of the app.

I've searched around a bit and modified my `firebase.json` to reflect the following:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "www",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [
      { "source":"/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}] }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I thought this worked, but today I pushed an update and it required me to clear my cache.  Does anyone have other ideas on how to force an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
"headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}]
```

**to this**

```
"headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control",  "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"]
```

Or this

```
"headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "public, max-age=0"}]
```

Also, you are setting the rule for `"source" : "/service-worker.js"`, is that what you want?

I think you want this :

```
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "/**",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

See what they do [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48738828/5466477)

This could reduce performances for the users

Comment: Thank you!!  Took care of it!

Comment: Can you think of any reason this would stop working?  I have to go to the Firebase dashboard and manually clear the previous releases again