# How to force update of Angular root path that has a redirect

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

The root of my angular site (e.g., "example.com") redirects, using the Angular router, to a subpage (e.g., "example.com/subpage"). When I type in "example.com," my browser loads the old version of the site from cache and then executes the redirect to "example.com/subpage". If I then refresh the page, it will then load the new version of site but only associate it with the subpage while keeping the old version in cache associated with the root page.

How do I tell the browser to refresh the cache for root url? Also,  how do I design the application to force old cached versions to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no good way besides redirecting to the root with the new version of the app to associate it in the cache. For future vetting, it looks like this technique should work. [How to force update Single Page Application (SPA) pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388614/how-to-force-update-single-page-application-spa-pages/45622588#45622588)