# Angular 4 Asp.Net core 1.x cache busting

Tags: angular, caching, webpack, asp.net-core

I have an issue with cache busting with angular 4 and Asp.net core project.

I use asp.net core with webpack to bundle files. we do append `asp-append-version="true"` on our index.html page and all of our chunkFilename have [chunkhash]. By this on deployment all changes are requested by the browser if the user logoff and login in again, as the index.html page will include the new `main-client.js?v=version` part.

The problem happens for users who **do not logout**, how can I force the browser to detect that index.html iteself has changed and see that the cached bundle ?version is not valid anymore?

Webpack:

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
module.exports = {

    devtool: isDevBuild ? 'inline-source-map' : false,

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
        alias: {
            jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
        }
    },

    entry: {
        'polyfills': './ClientApp/app/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './clientApp/app/vendor.ts',
        'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'chunk.[id].[chunkhash:8].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /node_modules/],
                use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-router-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            }, {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }, { // Load css files which are required in vendor.ts
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: isDevBuild
                        }
                    }
                })
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: { limit: 100000 }
                }]
            },
            { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['main-client', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        //new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./wwwroot/dist/']),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', 'window.jQuery': 'jquery' })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            },
            sourceMap: false
        })
    ])
};
```

And My Index page:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "App";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/preloader/preloader.css" asp-append-version="true" />

</head>
<body>

<app-root></app-root>

<div class="preloader">
    <div class="preloader-progress">
        <div class="preloader-progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
<script src="~/dist/polyfills.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/preloader/preloader.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer or just a suggestion, but have you taken a look at the concept of a service worker?

Comment: As I cannot edit my comment, this answer also came to mind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056808/detect-application-version-change-on-a-single-page-application

But this only applies if you update both back-end and front-end simultaneously.